# FreePBX custom autoprovision template (dlink)

Tags: asterisk

How I can create template for autoprovision manualy in FreePBX?

I want add support any Dlink phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) install OSS PBX End Point Manager module

2) in menu select connectivity->OSS endpoint template manager, press create new. Put in that template

3) setup via ssh web access to those files acordinly to dlink rules.

Comment: But, I cant select "Product" because I havent dlink product in field. Can I add dlink manualy or any idea?

Comment: Product field doesn't metter